# Implementing a Mealy Machine in Verilog

Tags: verilog, flipflop, state-machines, system-verilog

I have a piece of code that I don't understand:

```
always_ff @(posedge CLK)
state <= RST || ~A[0]===1'bx || ~A[1]===1'bx ? 0 : nextstate;
```

`A` is the input. What is this piece of code exactly doing? What is `~A[0]===1'bx` or `~A[1]===1'bx`?

My guess is that this code is checking if either one of the inputs aren't valid (`1'bx`). If one of the inputs aren't valid, we jump back to the starting state `0`.

But why the negation in `~A[0]===1'bx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a shortcut for:

```
A[0]===1'bx || A[0]===1'bz
```

If A[0] is 1'bx, ~A[0] will still be 1'bx.
If A[0] is 1'bz, ~A[0] will make it 1'bx.

I have to assume this is in a test bench because that code can not be synthesized.

A more meaningful way to write the code is:

```
state <= RST || $isunknown(A[1:0]) ? 0 : nextstate;
```